# PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[28000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user

Tags: php, sql, sql-server-2008

I have the following problem.

```
CONFIG: <?php

    // The database host
    $DATABASE_HOST = "localhost";

    // The default database
    $DEFAULT_DATABASE = "database";

    // The database login for the website
    $DATABASE_USER = "username";

    // The password
    $DATABASE_PASS = "password";

    // Create the connection
    $con = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=$DATABASE_HOST;database=$DEFAULT_DATABASE;", $DATABASE_USER, $DATABASE_PASS);

?>
```

As soon as I want to access, however, my homepage writes:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[28000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL
>   Server]Login failed for user 'username'.' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\database\config.php:16 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\database\config.php(16):
>   PDO->__construct('sqlsrv:server=l...', 'username', 'PR-dREnut=8a') #1
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\templates\vote.verif.php(10):
>   include('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #2
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\templates\header.php(197):
>   include('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php(2):
>   include('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #4 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\database\config.php on line 16 "

Comment: We speak __english__ here

Comment: does your instance of sql server use windows authentication or password authentication? also it's never a good idea to share real usernames or passwords